# Update Google App Engine to Python 2.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I've tried to update my app before by changing

> runtime: python27 , threadsafe: true , script: main.app"

It did work and was on python 2.7 but it didn't run properly I guess because my index.html didn't display when I went to the url http://dhsenviro.appspot.com. It is running on 2.5 now (because I want to keep it up). robots.txt is empty. How can I update it to 2.7 or should I update it to 3.x?

*app.yaml :*

```
application: dhsenviro
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|psd|swf))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|psd|swf))

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt 

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

*main.py :*

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'index.html'

    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app (application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()
```

I'd prefer not to upload my index.html, but I'm sure it's working properly.

**Edit:**

*main.py :*

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'index.html'

    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

class application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)

def main ():

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()
```

**CORRECT APP.YAML :**

```
application: dhsenviro
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|psd|swf))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|psd|swf))

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt
```

- url: /.*
  script: main.application

**CORRECT MAIN.PY**

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'index.html'

    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appengine does not support 3x (yet?). What is the error you encoutered? If it is error, should print something to the logs. A couple think that I notice,

- I don't think you need the run_wsgi_app anymore
- the script in yaml should be "main.application" instead of "main.py". Put the application variable as a global variable instead of local variable

Comment: `main.application` and set `application` as a global (rather than a local within `main`.

Comment: Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it

Comment: @DaveW.Smith Sorry but... How do I do that? Guessing thats in app.yaml?

Comment: In `app.yaml`, change to `script:` line to use `main.application`, and in `main.py`, move the `application = ...` line out of `main()` and to make it a class variable. Alternatively, change that to `app = ...` (and move it out of `main`). The point is to have `script:` point to a class variable.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith So I changed main.application, I tried to move `application = ...` but I wasn't sure where to put it. Here's the code now. Please make any necessary edits because it's not working.
I'll put it at the bottom of my question.

Comment: the application is an variable for sure, not a class. It is not working because it's a invalid python syntax, remove these part as well def main ():

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()

Comment: I am asking about your appengine logs, not what is printed in your browser

Comment: @marcadian **THANK YOU :D** I have no errors now (in the terminal and the site) and it works perfectly on 2.7 uploading it now. I'll change the code in the question too.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google's official [Migrating to Python 2.7](http://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27) doc, I think you have to do 2 things at least

- Update your `app.yaml`.

> > in GAE Python 2.5, the script attribute of the url handler is the path
> >     to the python source file.
>
> ```
> - url: /.*
>   script: main.py
> ```
>
> in Python 2.7 , it is changed to the a object
>
> ```
> - url: /.*
>   script: myapp.app
> ```
>
> > app is a  instance of the `webapp2.WSGIApplication`

- Updating your application to webapp2

> ```
> import webapp2
>
> class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
>   def get(self):
>     self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
>     self.response.out.write('Hello, WebApp World!')
>
> app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)])
>
> """ Old code:
> def main():
>   run_wsgi_app(app)
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>   main()
> """
> ```

Though you want to keep templates unchanged, webapp templates are deprecated.

> webapp templates are now deprecated. In their place, you can use
>   Jinja2, Django, or a templating system of your choice (as long as it's
>   written in pure Python).